# Returning multiple parameters in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

This should be a real simple question for a groovy person. What object type is def in the code below. I'm not allowed to use def's in my code, so I'm wondering what 'def' translates to? I tried Object, but that doesn't work. Does someone know?

```
final def (Date foo, String bar) = baz()
println foo
println bar

def baz() {
   return [ new Date(0), 'Test' ]
}
```

Comment: *"Returning multiple parameters"* is an [oxymoron](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron). A method takes *parameters* and returns a *value*. It doesn't return *parameters*.

Comment: Sure does, that's why it's groovy =) The code above works just fine. I just need to know what I can replace 'def' with.

Comment: My point is that none of that code is "parameters". The `(Date foo, String bar)` might share syntax *similar* to the syntax used for defining method parameters, but they are not parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code translates to / is compiler shorthand for:

```
List x = baz()
final Date foo = x[0]
final String bar = x[1]
```

where `x` isn't a real variable.

Comment: I got it, I'd like to do this all in one statement like this ??? (Date foo, String bar) = baz( new Date(), "Test" ). Is this not possible? I hate the fact our coding teams won't let us use the def statements since it takes forever to figure out what the replacement is, in cases like this.

Comment: @Wildview It is **syntactic shorthand** for defining and assigning multiple variables from a list. The syntax uses the `def` keyword. In this construct, `def` is not a substitute for an actual type, so it cannot be replaced with a type.

Comment: I could do this I guess. Date foo;
String bar;
(foo, bar) = baz( new Date(), "Test" ) but was hoping for a condensed version.